# How can you develop bottom-up JAX-WS web services referencing classes contained in separate jar files?

Tags: deployment, jar, shared-libraries, classloader, external

I am developing a Java EE 6 bottom-up JAX-WS to expose an EJB3.1 stateless session bean.  The web service in a WAR is failing to install on deployment because it references an external jar (or shared library) which one can assume is not loaded yet.

The common suggestion is to include the jars in the /lib folder, which does fix the issue, however the jars need to remain in this external shared library location and NOT in the ear file, because they amount to 30MB.

What are some techniques to get around this issue in a Websphere (WAS v.8) environment or any server environment.
Some suggestions I have found include:

```
   1. define classpath in META-INF file.    
   2. define the resources in deployment.xml    
   3. alter class loading order    
   4. (from ibm) In the case where the jars are part of a Shared Library configured on WebSphere Application Server, then a User Library must be used to configure the project for development before generating the WebService.
```

However, I have been unsuccessful to find any help online in these areas.   Is there another technique or does anyone know anything about accomplishing this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: If I specify the libraries in the META-INF using class-path, they are loaded before extensions, shared libraries..etc, but they are still loaded after the WAR which is not good.  Again, this isn't a runtime issue because the web services are created at deployment on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a ticket to IBM.   The libraries referenced by the web service are needed during deployment and must be bundled into the Ear in some fashion.  I threw them in the web-inf/lib folder.  However, if the referenced libraries then depend on additional libraries, these can be placed in the Shared Libraries.  Seems odd to me too, but let's all just admit "shared libraries" are a hack anyways.

If you still have issues, just make sure your class loading is set to parent_last.